# Problema al desplegar script python en heroku

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

Estoy tratando desplegar un script python en heroku, al momento del despliegue me arroja error:

El archivo **Procfile** contiene lo siguiente: **web gunicorn app:app**

Nombre el archivo python **app.py**

datos del log:

```
2022-04-25T22:24:19.186162+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-25 22:24:19 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-04-25T22:24:19.390763+00:00 app[web.1]: 3.4
2022-04-25T22:24:19.390764+00:00 app[web.1]: 201
2022-04-25T22:24:19.390884+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'.
2022-04-25T22:24:19.391069+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-25 22:24:19 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-04-25T22:24:19.436068+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-25 22:24:19 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-04-25T22:24:19.535845+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-25 22:24:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-04-25T22:24:19.535909+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-25 22:24:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2022-04-25T22:24:19.743365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
2022-04-25T22:24:19.931915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

EDIT: modifique el archivo procfile por **web: python3 app.py** y el script funciono en primera intancia, luego volvio a fallar, adjunto el log.

```
2022-04-26T01:01:18.303464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-04-26T01:01:18.453658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-04-26T01:01:18.604716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-04-26T01:01:18.730788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2022-04-26T01:00:12.337871+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-04-26T01:00:12.537109+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-04-26T01:00:12.541778+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-04-26T01:00:18.030632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3 app.py`
2022-04-26T01:00:21.810783+00:00 app[web.1]: 2.9
2022-04-26T01:00:21.810801+00:00 app[web.1]: 159
2022-04-26T01:01:18.303464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-04-26T01:01:18.453658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-04-26T01:01:18.604716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-04-26T01:01:18.730788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**codigo app.py**

```
import geopy
from geopy.distance import geodesic
from unittest import result
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import gunicorn

e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

# Obt    enemos la tabla

tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]

# Obtenemos todas las filass
rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")

output_rows = []
for row in rows:
        # obtenemos todas las columns
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    output_row = []
    if len(cells) > 0:
        for cell in cells:
            output_row.append(cell.text)
            output_rows.append(output_row)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)

dataset.columns = [
        "Fecha Local",
        "Fecha UTC",
        "Latitud",
        "Longitud",
        "Profundidad [Km]",
        "Magnitud",
        "Referencia Geográfica",
    ]
dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]] = dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
dataset_filter = dataset[
            (-27.100 <= dataset["Latitud"])
            & (dataset["Latitud"] <= -21.680)
            & (-72.150 <= dataset["Longitud"])
            & (dataset["Longitud"] <= -66.180)
            ]

tranque = (-24.39,-69.14)

latitud1 = dataset_filter['Latitud'].values[0]
longitud1 = dataset_filter['Longitud'].values[0]
profundidad = dataset_filter['Profundidad [Km]'].values[0]
magnitud = dataset_filter['Magnitud'].values[0]
magnitud2 = magnitud.split(' ')
magnitud3 = float(magnitud2[0])
magnitud4 = magnitud2[1]
delhi = (latitud1, longitud1)
distancia = int(round((geodesic(tranque, delhi).km)))

print (magnitud3)
print (distancia)


def bot_send_text(bot_message):
    
    bot_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    bot_chatID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()


def sismo_scraping():  
    string="A ocurrido un sismo en las cercanías " "\n""\n" "*Datos del sismo:*" "\n" #titulo con salto de linea
    
    for column in dataset_filter.head(1).columns:
        string += column +  " : " + str(dataset_filter[column].values[0]) + "\n"
          
    return string

def distancias():       
    string2="El sismo se registro a una *DISTANCIA* de  "  f'{str(distancia)}' "Km del punto x, y una *MAGNITUD* de " f'{str(magnitud3)}' "" f'{str(magnitud4)}'
    return string2
  

        
def main():
    ultimo_sismo = None
    # text3 = f'{amarillo()}'
    while True:
        text = f'{sismo_scraping()}'
        text2 = f'{distancias()}'
        if text != ultimo_sismo:
            bot_send_text(text)
            ultimo_sismo = text
            bot_send_text(text2)
            # bot_send_text(text3)
        time.sleep(60) 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Edit: creo que hay problemas para desplegar de forma automática con github

Comment: Es problema del código y sin verlo poco podemos hacer

Comment: editare la pregunta, realice una modificación al archivo procfile funciono, pero luego vuelve otro error.

Comment: Cuando tu script es un proceso que se ejecutará siempre debes especificarlo, no recuerdo como se hacía, espérame un momento.

Comment: ok ahi esta editada la pregunta

Comment: Creo que me equivoque, encontré esto https://help.heroku.com/W5ETWBQB/why-is-my-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: Gracias x tus respuestas